# приведение строки символов к __m128i

Tags: c++

как привести `string` к `__m128i`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <intrin.h>

char  string[] = " +-0098765432109876540.09876e-0248";
int   i;
__m128i  Xmm_SP = { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9};

int main()
{
    do {
        _mm_cmpeq_epi8(string, Xmm_SP);
    } while (1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно загрузить блок из невыровненного адреса посредством встроенной функции `_mm_loadu_si128`:

```
#include <intrin.h>

int main()
{
    auto const & text{" +-0098765432109876540.09876e-0248"};
    __m128i xmm_sp{0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9};
    __m128i xmm_text{_mm_loadu_si128(static_cast<__m128i const *>(static_cast<void const *>(static_cast<char const *>(text))))};
    do
    {
        _mm_cmpeq_epi8(xmm_text, xmm_sp);
    }
    while (1);
}
```

Comment: строка не должна быть константой, предполагается что функция будет получать строку неизвестного содержимого.

Comment: @ИльяК ¿И что? На содержимое ответа это никак не повлияет.

Comment: хорошо. у меня сейчас просто нет возможности проверить то ли это что я искал, а что вы скажите про__m128i _mm_set_epi8 (char e15, char e14, char e13, char e12, char e11, char e10, char e9, char e8, char e7, char e6, char e5, char e4, char e3, char e2, char e1, char e0)

Comment: @ИльяК А это то, что будет вызываться при инициализации `xmm_sp`;

Comment: смог проверить, указанный вами способ делает именно то что нужно, хотя внешне выглядит как попытка насильно скормить компилятору то что он ни за что бы не согласился съесть знай он что это такое.